# how to get memberID to transfer from one page to another, javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a speech bubble(balloon) on a canvas. 
I allow a user to click on this balloon to see more information about the balloon.

As the user clicks, a new page is popped up and I want to send the mem_ID to the new page so that I can do a query on the new page and post data about the member on the new page.

```
      // listen for clicks on the balloon, opens a hyperlink attached to the balloon. 
             $("#balloon").click(function popMessage(e) {
                 $("#balloon").hide();

                 // hyperlink opens a new window upon click on the bubble
                 return !window.open('About.aspx?mem_ID' + mem_ID, "pop", "width=1000,height=900"); 

             });
```

So this is how I am planning to send the member_ID to the new page.

Now how can I retrieve this on the new page, so I can do something with it?

I have a text box on the new page and would like to print this ID just to check if it is transferring:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">




    var id = <%=Request["mem_ID"]%>

    document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value = id;




</script>
```

it shows up as 'undefined' in the text box.....any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open('About.aspx?mem_ID'
```

should be

```
window.open('About.aspx?mem_ID='
```

BUT, you don't want to transfer it like that as it will expose sensitive data to an attacker via the url:  either check the id on the server side when it's first received or else store it in session state when the user logs in.

**update:**

your child page:

```
var id = <%=Request["mem_ID"]%>
```

should be

```
var id = "<%=Request["mem_ID"]%>";
```

Also... attackers can be internal too... for an internal app, session state is the simplest way to implement basic cross-page data integrity.

Comment: internal usage. so not exposed to outside attackers. also, i am trying to not use session variables with C#. 

but your insight was helpful!! thanks.

however, no I get an error in my child page:-

'TQR002393' is undefined. haha this is the actual member id... which means it was passed to the child page. somehow the child page thinks this not a value but a defined var???

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead ::

```
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value = '<%=Request["mem_ID"]%>';
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: it shows up as a blank text box. atleast it is not undefined (on the bright side) haha. However when I check on my parent page. mem_ID has a value just before it is being passed on to the child page. Any idea?

Comment: @Philo, can you does your popup window URL contain the "mem_ID"? can you share the exact url?

Comment: as per my coding, it pops up a new window, but the window doesn't show the url. lol

also I edited my question a bit, I defined a var in the child page, set its value to request<mem_ID> and posted it back on the text box. and now it shows up as 'undefined'

Comment: does the address bar absent in pop window? Can you share the print screen?